# How to access Thread Name from Other function?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I want to access the thread from other function in the same class.
For example

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Send1));
    thread1.Start();
}

private void stop_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     thread1.Stop();
}
```

I wan to access thead1 from stop_btn_Click event. Both functions are in the same class Form1.

Comment: `Thread.Abort` is extremely dangerous and should not be used.  (`Thread.Stop` does not exist)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare `private Thread thread1;` on the class level rather than method

```
class ClassName
{
    private Thread workerThread = null;

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Send1));
        workerThread.Start();
    }

    private void stop_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         this.workerThread.Stop();
    }
}
```

By looking at the method name `timer1_Tick()` I can assume that you are simulating a timer behaviour. Take a look at the [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) and [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) classes perhaps you'll find them more useful for your case.

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the thread in a private field in the form.

You also need to figure out what should happen if the user clicks `Start` twice; you may want to check whether the thread is already running, or use a list of threads.

Answer (score 1):

you could take the variable outside the method (moving it into the class as a field):

```
private Thread thread1 = null;

void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Send1));
    thread1.Start();
}


private void stop_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (thread1 != null) 
         thread1.Stop();
}
```